# What's the cheapest way to get from Edmonton International Airport to Jasper national park?

Tags: budget, transportation, national-parks, alberta, jasper

Some private companies offer ~$80 rides directly from the airport to Jasper, while Greyhound charges ~$40 from the *city* (Edmonton) to Jasper. Currently it seems that the cheapest option would be a bus to the city and a bus (Greyhound) to the park. Any other options?

Comment: Would you consider hitchhiking?

Comment: @MarkMayo, only if it's popular enough to count on, i.e. that I won't have to spend 2hrs waiting to be picked up.

Answer (score 4):

Via Rail has service from Edmonton to Jasper every Sunday, Tuesday and Friday, and return service every Monday, Wednesday and Saturday. The lowest fare I could find was $182.70 return. Probably not what you want.

Greyhound Canada has daily service (though it leaves Edmonton at 12:30 am!) and I was quoted a price of $72.70 return for a 14-day advance purchase on their web site. This is the best option I could find, though with that departure time you should probably plan to spend a few hours sightseeing in Edmonton.

[Edmonton also has the "747" bus](http://www.edmonton.ca/transportation/ets/alerts_routes_schedules_maps/edmonton-international-airport.aspx) which runs between the airport and Century Park Station; this costs $5. You'll then need to take the 501 train ($3.20) to Bay Enterprise Square Station to [get to Greyhound](https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/Century+Park+Station,+Edmonton,+AB,+Canada/Greyhound,+103+Street+Northwest,+Edmonton,+AB,+Canada/@53.5012518,-113.5498203,13z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x53a01ee28e8f4341:0xf826322b19e60994!2m2!1d-113.516093!2d53.457229!1m5!1m1!1s0x53a02248d7647dcb:0xdbbc45e06aed2dad!2m2!1d-113.49791!2d53.545286!3e3), which is a few blocks away from that station. The Via Rail train station is [not very easily accessible](https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/Century+Park+Station,+Canada/Via+Rail+Canada+Inc,+121+Street+Northwest,+Edmonton,+AB,+Canada/@53.5192941,-113.5973699,12z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x53a01ee28e8f4341:0xf826322b19e60994!2m2!1d-113.516093!2d53.457229!1m5!1m1!1s0x539ff761ebd08989:0x94bc1f5d33655cc7!2m2!1d-113.5307211!2d53.5788836!3e3) via public transit, but it can be done with a bit of walking.

I wasn't able to find any other options cheaper than Greyhound, though there is always hitchhiking.

Answer (score 4):

At $80 from the airport directly to Jasper vs $40+ from city center you value your time at nearly nothing. You will waste considerable time traveling to downtown, and then waiting until midnight for the bus. All for about $30.

Or you can land at the airport, get on a highway bus and be in Jasper in about 5 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you're travelling in a group, the cheapest way could be renting a car in Edmonton and returning it in Jasper.

Note that the one-way renting prices of Edmonton<->Jasper are much cheaper than Calgary<->Banff.